# Conditional Statement no longer evaluating correctly?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, conditional-statements

I'm having a little trouble with a conditional statement I wrote a while back.

```
if ($select -gt 0 -and $select -le $numfiles){...}else{...}
```

All it's supposed to do is take the user input, $select, and compare it to the number of files in the current directory, $numfiles.

I've checked in the debugger, and found that both variables do receive values. In the instance I'm running, it should evaulate as true.

```
$select = 2
$numfiles = 11
$select -gt 0 -and $select -le $numfiles
True
```

Yet it evaluates as false, unless $select is equal to 1.

I'm not sure what has changed, since it hasn't been a problem for over a month.

Comment: What is the actual type and value of `$select`, and how is the value assigned to the variable?

Comment: $select receives a value from read-Host, like so:

     $select= read-Host 'Select a file to generate simplified copy'

Comment: Modified my answer below, sorry about the confusion with .ToInt32()..

Comment: That answers only part of my question. What are the actual value and type of `$select` at the point where the comparison seems to work incorrectly?

Comment: If you get a value from Read-Host it will be [string], however your $numfiles is probably an [int]. You can't compare two different datatypes even though $select -gt 0 generates 'True', $select -le $numfiles will generate 'False'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the variables are of the correct datatypes

```
$select.GetType().name
$numfiles.GetType().name
```

If one of them is string cast them as [int] like so:

```
$select -as [int] -gt 0 -and $select -as [int] -le $numfiles
```

Comment: Just casted $select, it works now. I find it very strange though, what could have possibly changed from a month ago when I first wrote it? The particular function that contained that statement has not been modified since.

Comment: Here's how I believe it works: Since the comparing variable, $select, is [string] - powershell casts $numfiles.ToString(). Becouse $select is only one character, it only compares to the first character in $numfiles, which is 1. I.e. 2 -le 1 = False.

Comment: $numfiles was probably somewhere between 2 and 9 before and this month it has grown to >= 10. Sounds plausible?

Comment: Sounds spot on. I hadn't tested more that 9 files at once until this point. Had no idea powershell would recast an integer to a string.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the two expressions are being evaluated separately, I would suggest wrapping them in parentheses.

```
if (($select -gt 0) -and ($select -le $numfiles)){...}else{...}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, since `-gt` and `-le` have [higher precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847842.aspx) than `-and`.

Comment: I agree, it shouldn't be, in theory.

Comment: Do you have a profile script? If so, launch PowerShell with `-NoProfile` and test.